# How to send message to virtual port in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, serial-port, virtual

I'm starting a project where a need to control some external device using an iPad.

My device is connected via USB, and as far as I know, the iPad should detect it as a virtual port, but I'm having some problems in finding how can I make my iPad app send messages to my device.

The first part of my project consist on just sending messages, later I'll be receiving from external devices, but just by knowing how to communicate with virtual port I think I can go on.

So, my questions are:

1) Do iPad communicate with external devices connected via USB as virtual ports?

2) How can I send messages to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to something via USB (over the lightning connector) you'll need to join the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

Comment: Thanks! This could be what I was looking for! just a quick question... The MFi program is also for developers who use non apple hardware?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, yes - MFi is a way for you to interface a device you build with an Apple iOS device and gain a "Made For iXXX" for your third party/non-Apple hardware.